# EPSV followed by LPSV command in FTP server

Tags: java, ftp

We wrote our own FTP server , but today we are facing some issue .

Our FTP client is sending EPSV followed by LPSV command.

As per my understanding as you entered in Extened mode there is no need for LPSV

So question is - IS this bug form Client that he is sending LPSV right after EPSV.

```
[DEBUG]  Thread_com FTPDaemon Thread pool: FTP<EPSV
[DEBUG]   Thread_comFTPDaemon Thread pool: FTP>Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||49027|)
[DEBUG]  - Thread_comFTPDaemon Thread pool: FTP<LPSV // Did not understand this
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bug in the client but it might also be your server sending an unexpected response to EPSV.  It is unknown what your server really has sent but at least there is not status code shown for the response in your debug output, so maybe your server has not send one. In that case the client would not be able to process the response like you have intended and thus will probably try a different command assuming that your server does not understand EPSV.

Comment: +1 Though I would rather expect the client to disconnect upon seeing a response that violates an FTP protocol specification.

Answer (score 0):

Your text mentions

> Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||49027|)

Shouldn't it be sending back the response code as well?

> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||49027|)